# Why is it giving me a NoSuchElementException error

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

```
public static void getBooks()throws FileNotFoundException{

  Scanner input = new Scanner(bookFile);
  String line = input.nextLine();
  bookNum = 1;

  while (input.hasNextLine()) {
     bookNum += 1;
     line = input.nextLine();
  }

  bookarray = new String[3][bookNum];

  for (int y = 0; y < bookNum; y++){
     bookarray [0][y] = line.substring(0,10);
     bookarray [1][y] = line.substring(11,15);
     bookarray [2][y] = line.substring(17,18);
     line = input.nextLine();
  }     
}
```

The program compiles but it gives me an error that looks like this:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
pointing at the line = input.nextLine(); line, I don't understand why.

Comment: It gives you that exception because, at some point, no next line exists.

Comment: Your scanner has no more lines to read as you're already done it in the first while loop (see  `while(input.hasNextLine())`)

Comment: @ZouZou how can I fix it then I tried to put input.nextLine(); instead of line = input.nextLine(); but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @user3424068 That won't change anything. You can close your scanner and reopen it after the while loop. After the while, `input.close(); input = new Scanner(bookFile);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your `while` loop you exhaust your `Scanner`objects so there are no lines left in it.

Later when you call `nextLine()` in your `for` loop it will throw an exception obviously since you have already iterated over your lines.

My suggestion is to use a `List` and a pojo instead:

```
List<MyBookPojo> bookPojos = new ArrayList<MyBookPojo>();
```

where `MyBookPojo` can contain those 3 `String`s you are extracting from each line.

So this way you can add an arbitrary number of objects to your list.